# Find the given binary matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

Consider a binary square matrix $A$ ,(that is elements are either $1$ or $0$). You are given $Sum$ of elements of $each$ $row$ and $column$ ,that is you are given $r_i$ where $r_i$ means $Sum$ of its elements in $i$ th $row$ and same for column $i$ $Sum$ is  $c_i$ . Find the binary matrix.

How can i find the matrix, i mean for small matrix i could use pen and paper and for medium sized matrix i could check each random permutation but for large ones it is not possible. Is there any good algorithm for this question ?

Comment: Is the sum given modulo $2$ or is the raw sum given?

Comment: @paulinho a raw sum

Comment: To find one of the solutions, you might try a greedy algorithm, setting a one at $(i,j)$ position, where $r_i$ and $c_j$ are maximum, then updating the sums etc.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the solution is far from unique.  For example, both $\pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr}$ have row and column sums $1$.

This can be considered as a [maximum flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) with sources $r_i$ and sinks $c_i$, and upper bounds of $1$ on each arc.  Polynomial-time algorithms are available.